# I need to know which ecosystems we can remove from React when using Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have some question to know
=== I know that Next comes to solve many React issues,What are these problems that I face I am not talking about server side rendering and solid state relays

Comment: You have not shown what you did. Show, don't explain.

Answer (score 1):

Just use flex.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  background: purple;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}

.container div:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I don't want to start from the white space but the start of the color at the beginning can I use translateX ?

Comment: If you mean the whitespace that appears because the images are skewed at start and end you can use position or negative margin on `.container` to expand its width and cut off the whitespace with overflow hidden.